# multiple numpy version on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, numpy

I am running Mac OS X 10.8.4.

Python 2.7 is installed by installing command line tools in Xcode.

Apple is managing a version of numpy (1.6.1) located at

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy
```

I use

```
sudo easy_install numpy
```

to install a version (1.7.x). It is put at location

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

In python, when

```
import numpy
```

it actually imports the 1.6.1 one (managed by apple).

Howe can I choose the 1.7.x one installed by `easy_install`?

Comment: Can you type `which easy_install` into the command line and paste the results?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/easy_install`

Comment: @reijz: in that case, you need to use `/usr/local/bin/python` to make use of numpy 1.7.

Comment: @tiago I do not have such a python. My preference is just to use the default python coming with the commandline tools in Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use == to specify the version:

```
easy_install numpy==1.6
```

I prefer pip:

```
easy_install pip
pip install numpy==1.6
```

EDIT:
To make use of multiple installed versions of a package you could use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/) assuming you don't need multiple versions of the package within the same project

[source](http://shtuff.it/article/14/Python_-_install_specific_version_with_pip_or_easy_install)

Comment: It seems they want to select which numpy version is being used at runtime, not installed.

Comment: The question is not which version to install. Just two versions of numpy are installed, how to choose the one I want?

Comment: I use virtualenv to isolate different projects with different package dependencies, added an edit